# How to add radio buttons which have multiple choice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to use use a popup menu for registration and I have to use radio button on it somewhere. It should have multiple choices and just one is able to chosen.

Here is my code:

Here is my PersonModel.js

```
define([
'kendo/kendo.data.min', 'robe/Validations'], function () {

var PersonModel = kendo.data.Model.define({
    id: "oid",
    fields: {
        oid: {
            editable: false,
            nullable: true,
            type: "string"
        },
        lastUpdated: {
            editable: true,
            nullable: true,
            type: "string"
        },
        tckNo:{
            editable:true,
            nullable:false,
            type:"string",
            validation :getValidations("tckNo","T.C. Kimlik Numarası",true,false,11,11,"[0-9]")
        },
        name: {
            editable: true,
            nullable: false,
            type: "string"
        },
        surname: {
            editable: true,
            nullable: false,
            type: "string"
        },
        birthday: {
            editable: true,
            nullable: false,
            type: "date"
        },
        isSingle:{
            editable:true,
            nullable:false,
            type:"boolean"
        }
    }
});
return PersonModel;});
```

Here is PersonDataSource.js

```
define(['common/SingletonDataSource', './PersonModel'], function (SingletonDataSource, personModel) {

var personDataSource = SingletonDataSource.define({
    name: "personDataSource",
    parameters: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                type: "GET",
                url: AdminApp.getBackendURL() + "person/all",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            update: {
                type: "POST",
                url: AdminApp.getBackendURL() + "person",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            destroy: {
                type: "DELETE",
                url: AdminApp.getBackendURL() + "person",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            create: {
                type: "PUT",
                url: AdminApp.getBackendURL() + "person",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json"
            },
            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                if (operation !== "read") {
                    return kendo.stringify(options);
                }
            }
        },
        batch: false,
        pageSize: 25,
        schema: {
            model: personModel
        }
    }
});

return personDataSource;});
```

And here is PersonManagement.js :

```
 define([
    'text!./PersonManagement.html',
    './PersonDataSource',
    'kendo/kendo.grid.min',
    'robe/view/RobeView'],
function(view,PersonDataSource){
    var PersonManagementView = require('robe/view/RobeView').define({
        name:"PersonManagementView",
        html:view,
        containerId:"container",
        initialize:function(){
            var grid = $("#personGrid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: PersonDataSource.get(),
                sortable: true,
                autoBind: false,
                pageable: {
                    refresh: true
                },
                toolbar: [
                    {
                        name: "create",
                        text: "Yeni Kişi"
                    }
                ],
                columns: [
                    {
                        field:"tckNo",
                        title:"TC Kimlik Numarası",
                        format:"{0:n0}"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "name",
                        title: "Ad"

                    },
                    {
                        field: "surname",
                        title: "Soyad"
                    },
                    {
                        field: "birthday",
                        title: "Doğum Günü"
                    },
                    {
                        command: [
                            {
                                name: "edit",
                                text: {
                                    edit:   "",
                                    update: "Tamam",
                                    cancel: "İptal"
                                },
                                className: "grid-command-iconfix"
                            },
                            {
                                name: "destroy",
                                text: "",
                                className: "grid-command-iconfix"
                            }
                        ],
                        title: "&nbsp;",
                        width: "120px"
                    }
                ],
                editable: {
                    mode: "popup",
                    window: {
                        title: "Kayıt".i18n()
                    },
                    confirmation: "Silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?".i18n(),
                    confirmDelete: "Yes"
                }
            });
        }
    });
    return PersonManagementView;
}
```

);

Can you help me please?

Comment: This isn't really an answer, and it's more UX related, but traditionally I'd think checkboxes would be used for multiple selection. Typically I'd expect to only be allowed to select on option for a radio button list.

Maybe you could switch to a checkbox list instead?

Answer (score 0):

You have too use checkboxes.
Radio-Buttons don't allow multiple selection.

Comment: I don't want to multiple selection I want to one selection from multiple choices(options).

Comment: You can't. Radio buttons are there for a single choice. For multiple choices, you need checkboxes. Check that at least one is checked with jQuery. Got the same Problem a month ago.

Comment: I think I couldn't achive to explain. I don't want to multiple choose. I mean user can just do one select from multiple options. I know how is radio buttons work. Do you understand now friend? thank you for your interests.

Comment: Okay so maybe you could fiddle it?  I really dont unterstand your problem

Comment: F.e you are a person okey, and you have a marital status from just 3 options. You may be single, you may be married and you may be widow. You can't have any options for this question and YOU CAN NOT SELECT 2 OPTİONS ON SAME TIME. YOU MUST SELECT JUST ONE.